# Is it possible to persist the viewstate between pages in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, viewstate

I have a `button` (view state enabled) in Master web page and set it to `visible=false` in one of the child web pages. If a second child page is opened, the button state (`visible=false)` is not persisting.

It seems **viewstate** is only valid for one page and is not transferred to other web pages. Is there some kind of trick to make **viewstate** global for all web pages?

Answer (score 15):

No, viewstate is page specific. You will need to use something like a session variable or a querystring parameter to pass your state between pages.

Answer (score 3):

No, You cannot make view state global, they are page specific. I would suggest to use cookies if you really want to make it client side otherwise you can use session.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store on a "global" level, you should be using the Application State. You could also use Cache Object. 
You may be wanting to pass values from one page to another, you can achieve this by using the Context object in combination with the Server.Transfer.

1) You need a public property on the source page returning the  Value to pass

```
namespace SomeNameSpace
{
    public partial class SourcePage: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string ValueToPass
        {
            get
            {
                if (Context.Items["ValueToPass"] == null)
                    Context.Items["ValueToPass"] = string.Empty;
                return (string)Context.Items["ValueToPass"];
            }
            set
            {
                Context.Items["ValueToPass"] = value;
            }
        }
        ........
    }
}
```

2) Do a Server.Transfer(DestinationPage.aspx)
3) In the Page_Load event of the destination page

```
namespace SomeNameSpace
{
    public partial class SourcePage: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var value = this.Context.Items["ValueToPass"];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps